# Consulta HQL pasándole dato a una clave foránea

Tags: base-de-datos, hibernate, grails, hql

A continuación se mostrarán las dos tablas con sus respectivos campos:

***GuiaDocente:*** id, curso, modalidad, asignatura_ing

***Materia:*** id, guia_docente_id, modulo, materia, caracter, creditos, unidad_temporal, profesor_asignatura, email, horario_atencion, coordinador_curso, coordinador_modulo

El tipo de relación entre GuiaDocente y Materia es de '1 a 1'.

**Quiero hacer una consulta pasándole un dato a la clave foránea "guia_docente_id", tal como se muestra en el siguiente código:**

```
class GuiaDocenteService { 
 def idMateria(idGuiaDocente){
  Materia.executeQuery("select tablaMateria.id " +
       "from Materia tablaMateria " +
       "where tablaMateria.guia_docente_id=?", [idGuiaDocente])
 }
}
```

Sin embargo, me muestran los siguientes errores:

> Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateQueryException:
>   could not resolve property: guia_docente_id of:
>   generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia [select tablaMateria.id
>   from generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia tablaMateria where
>   tablaMateria.guia_docente_id=?]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   guia_docente_id of: generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia
>   [select tablaMateria.id from
>   generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia tablaMateria where
>   tablaMateria.guia_docente_id=?]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   guia_docente_id of: generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia
>   [select tablaMateria.id from
>   generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia tablaMateria where
>   tablaMateria.guia_docente_id=?]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:
>   guia_docente_id of: generacionGuiasDocentes.guiaDocente.Materia

En el controlador, se muestra el siguiente código:

```
class GuiaDocenteController {
     def idMateria(){
        def idGuiaDocente = params.id
        def consultaIdMateria = guiaDocenteService.idMateria(idGuiaDocente)

        render consultaIdMateria as JSON
    }
}
```

En el fichero jQuery se muestra el siguiente código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//--- asignatura ---
    $(".btnActualizaAsignatura").click(function () {

        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
        }

        URL = enlaceObjetos.urlIdAsignatura;

        actualizaFormulario(URL);
    })
});

    function actualizaFormulario(URL) {

        var datos, idGuiaDocente, idParam;

        idGuiaDocente = localStorage.getItem("idGuiaDocente");
        idParam = $.param({id: idGuiaDocente});

        datos = $("#idFormulario").serialize() + "&" + idParam;

        alert("El resultado es: " + idGuiaDocente);
        alert("Datos: " + datos);

        peticionConDatosCallBackAjax(URL, parseInt(datos), function (data){

            if(data.toString() === ""){
                //se inserta
                alert("El dato es: " + data);
            }else{
                //se actualiza
            }
        });
    }
```

En el modelo "Materia", se muestra el siguiente código:

```
class Materia {

    String modulo
    String materia
    String caracter
    String creditos
    String unidad_temporal
    String profesor_asignatura
    String email
    String horario_atencion
    String coordinador_curso
    String coordinador_modulo

    static belongsTo = [guiaDocente:GuiaDocente]

    static constraints = {
        modulo nullable: true
        materia nullable: true
        caracter nullable: true
        creditos nullable: true
        unidad_temporal nullable: true
        profesor_asignatura nullable: true
        email nullable: true
        horario_atencion nullable: true
        coordinador_curso nullable: true
        coordinador_modulo nullable: true
    }
}
```

En el modelo "GuiaDocente" se muestra el siguiente código:

```
class GuiaDocente {

    String curso
    String modalidad
    String asignatura_ing

    static belongsTo = [asignatura:Asignatura]
    static hasOne = [materia:Materia]

    static constraints = {
        curso blank: false
        modalidad blank: false
        asignatura_ing nullable: true
        materia nullable: true
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código de la clase (la clase, no la tabla) `TablaMateria`?

Comment: No conozco grails, pero en HQL en Java trabajas con las entidades y sus relaciones; no con la estructura de tablas. Así que en Java la cosa sería: `where materia.guia_docente.id`

Comment: Al final se ha modificado la línea de código que me has especificado, de la siguiente forma: `"where tablaMateria.guiaDocente.id=?", [idGuiaDocente]`. El problema está solucionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ha resuelto el problema, se ha modificado el siguiente código...

```
class GuiaDocenteService { 
 def idMateria(idGuiaDocente){

  Materia.executeQuery("select tablaMateria.id " +
       "from Materia tablaMateria " +
       "where tablaMateria.guia_docente_id=?", [idGuiaDocente])
 }
}
```

por el que se muestra a continuación...

```
class GuiaDocenteService { 
 def idMateria(idGuiaDocente){

  Materia.executeQuery("select tablaMateria.id " +
       "from Materia tablaMateria " +
       "where tablaMateria.guiaDocente.id=?", [idGuiaDocente])
 }
}
```